# Will replicating Global Data on an OpenCL compliant device improve performance?

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpgpu, amd-processor

I have a pretty small dataset, but large enough that it won't fit in the workspace or private memories in any GPU currently on the market. What this means is that each kernel must access the data in the global memory on the GPU. If I replicate this data to multiple copies in the global memory, can it increase performance/reduce latency, or is the memory controller restrictive and will only allow one core to access the global memory at a time? If this is device specific, are there any models which have this feature?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you attempting to run multiple kernels simultaneously on the GPU, hence multiple kernels will access the same buffer simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very much bound by the memory controller of the video card, and multiple copies of the same data won't help you. I am unaware of a gpu having more than one memory controller for global access.

Your access pattern of the memory will greatly effect the overall throughput of your kernel. Do you have a specific example/kernel that you need optimized?

Comment: Not yet, but thanks for your answer. Basically I have a "three dimensional array" which stores data that has to be counted for each iteration in the GPU which implies that every time a kernel wants to analyze some data, it must iterate through the entire array.

Comment: A mainstream level gaming gpu has 150GB/s peak bandwidth. Local memory(LDS) can be 5TB/s while private register accessing can be 15TB/s + . Also it has 2GB global memory generally which is more than enough to pressure gpu to limits. GPU and especially AMD types has pretty good bandiwdth when you use all cores at the same time and on different bytes(also different cache lines). To hide memory latency, you make concurrent kernels or just optimize a single kernel to have more occupancy.

Comment: A simple, general optimization for global memory access is to take advantage of coalescence by reading adjacent memory addresses in close proximity to each other. Do a search for "coalesced access opencl" and you will find a lot of examples of what I mean by this. When reusing global data multiple times, access times are usually reduced a lot when you copy it to local memory.